# White space being inserted before a semicolon in asm-mode

Tags: indentation, comment

When I try to insert a semicolon in my code (in `asm-mode`) it seems to indent a certain number of tabs like this (usually 4 it seems):

```
D               ;
```

And if I put another semicolon on the next line it will indent one tab so it looks like this and add another semicolon even though I only pressed it once:

```
D               ;
    ;;
```

I am sure this is some helpful auto-complete technique, but I am just trying to do commands with a semicolon inside of it like <kbd>0;JEQ</kbd> but since I am an Emacs noob I don't know where to look to deactivate this. I searched with different queries looking for this problem, but I am having trouble finding it which is weird since everything else I looked up was easily answerable either from the Emacs manual or some other site. Can anyone point me to which option I can change so no white space is inserted?

Edit: 
Here is what option I changed my comment button to:

[image: asm comment char]

Is this correct? Basically, I just deleted the comment char which was ";" to what it is now which is "/", but like I say the same problem happens where when I press the semicolon key I get a slash instead and my slash key still gives me a slash.

Comment: What major mode is this, `asm-mode`?

Comment: Good call -- that looks fairly assemblerish, and in `asm-mode` I see that `C-h k ;` reports that `;` is bound to `asm-comment`. Presumably `;` is not a comment in the language being used here. `M-x customize-option RET asm-comment-char` would deal to that. (That might well not be the only misconfiguration for this language, however.)

Comment: Yes it does say I am in asm-mode, and I tried M-x customize-option RET asm-comment-char, but I don't seem to know how to do it. Do I type it all one line? I tried M-x customize-option and then it asked me which variable to customize but I couldn't seem to get the rest of it to work. Also // and /**/ work for commenting which is strange since I would think that if  ; is used for commenting then those wouldn't work?

Comment: @phils It seems I was successful in changing ";" comment char to "/" (it would only let me do one letter?). But now whenever I type the button on my keyboard that used to be semicolon it writes a "/". Like I say the double slash for comments already seem to be highlighted like I want, but I just want it so whenever I type a semicolon it doesn't indent a bunch. Did I do something wrong perhaps?

Comment: Based on my test, `asm-comment-char` tells the mode which key to bind to the `asm-comment` command, so typing `/` should now do the commenting action, and typing `;` should insert a semicolon. You might need to revert your existing asm-mode buffers for that change to be picked up?

Comment: @phils how do I revert my existing asm-mode buffers? I tried to save and apply like it says on the interface, but I don't know what I should do beyond that. I also tried to hit the button on the top left which says apply setting and save for future sessions but that didn't work either. I put an edit above showing what my settings look like but I don't know what to do beyond that. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: `M-x revert-buffer`; or kill the buffer and re-visit it; or use something like `M-x ibuffer` to mark and revert buffers en-masse -- `* M asm-mode RET` to mark and `V` to revert, in `ibuffer`.

Comment: It seems that `asm-mode` figures out which character is used for comments when it's initialized, so even trying to redefine comment key to run `self-insert-command` isn't solving this problem.

Comment: @phils Wow, I can't believe that actually worked! I just used the first command and it worked just like I wanted it to. Thanks a lot, but would you mind explaining a bit about why it worked, I am still not sure what reverting a buffer would do?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 Thanks for the help, I would try that but phils' answer seems to work for me so far. What does self-insert-command do? Also thanks a lot for the edits, I think my question must have been confusing since I didn't really know what was going on ha.

Comment: `self-insert-command` inserts the character that invoked it. In file-visiting buffers, most un-modified characters are bound to `self-insert-command` so that, for instance, typing `x` inserts an `x` into the buffer. (Everything you do interactively with Emacs is invoking a command of some sort.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `asm-mode`, <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> reports that <kbd>;</kbd> is bound to `asm-comment`.

The Commentary for `asm-mode.el` (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `asm-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>) says:

```
This minor mode is based on text mode.  It defines a private abbrev table
that can be used to save abbrevs for assembler mnemonics.  It binds just
five keys:

        TAB             tab to next tab stop
        :               outdent preceding label, tab to tab stop
        comment char    place or move comment
                        asm-comment-char specifies which character this is;
                        you can use a different character in different
                        Asm mode buffers.
        C-j, C-m        newline and tab to tab stop

Code is indented to the first tab stop level.

This mode runs two hooks:
  1) An asm-mode-set-comment-hook before the part of the initialization
depending on asm-comment-char, and
  2) an asm-mode-hook at the end of initialization.
```

So the variable `asm-comment-char` defines the comment character, and the mode uses this value to bind the associated key to the `asm-comment` command (i.e. "place or move comment").

You can configure this value globally via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `asm-comment-char` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Exactly how this feature works is entirely up to how the mode is written.  In this case I can see that when the `asm-mode` function is called it generates a new local keymap for the buffer which inherits from `asm-mode-map`, and it defines the comment key in there.

Immediately before it does that it runs `asm-mode-set-comment-hook`, so one could also set a value for `asm-comment-char` (potentially a buffer-local value) using that hook, instead of customizing the option globally.

All of this commenting configuration happens when the `asm-mode` function runs, so changing the global value doesn't affect existing `asm-mode` buffers; but you could just run `M-x asm-mode` in a buffer to get it to pick on on a change to `asm-comment-char`, or you could revert the buffer(s), or re-visit them.

e.g.:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `revert-buffer`
- or kill the buffer and re-visit it
- or use something like <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ibuffer` to mark and revert buffers en-masse

In `ibuffer` that would be <kbd>*</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> `asm-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> to mark, and <kbd>V</kbd> to revert.

Note that the way the keymap is generated means that each `asm-mode` buffer has its own independent comment key binding, so reverting a single buffer will not affect the pre-existing comment bindings in other `asm-mode` buffers, so reverting them *all* after a change to the global comment char option would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

A quick hack to disable this confusing functionality entirely is:

```
(advice-add #'asm-comment :override #'self-insert-command)
```

Then pressing your comment character will just insert it like you were expecting.